# Creating own mail provider for Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

Sometimes we have to integrate custom mail provider. But Laravel has a fixed list of them. Here they are:

- SMTP
- sendmail
- ses
- Mailgun
- Mandrill
- Sparkpost

Instructions for these drivers you can find in `framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/TransportManager.php`

The problem is that those instructions are fixed. Of course you can modify vendor-file but will be a dirty hack. So In the answer I'll provide some instruction how to implement your own custom mail driver in right way.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**First of all** we have to create custom `Transport` for our mailer.

Our mailer will communicate with another server by some API interface. File bellow is a model so I've put it to my Model's folder. If you haven't separate folder for models you can just put the file into `app` directory.

Lets call it `SmithTransport.php`:

```
<?php 

use GuzzleHttp\ClientInterface;
use Illuminate\Mail\Transport\Transport;

class SmithTransport extends Transport
{
    protected $client;

    protected $key;

    protected $domain;

    protected $url;

    public function __construct(ClientInterface $client, $key, $domain)
    {
        $this->key = $key;
        $this->client = $client;
        $this->setDomain($domain);
    }

    public function send(Swift_Mime_Message $message, &$failedRecipients = null)
    {
        $this->beforeSendPerformed($message);

        $options = ['auth' => ['api', $this->key]];

        $message->setBcc([]);

        $from_email = '';
        $from_name = '';
        $to_email = '';
        $to_name = '';

        foreach ($message->getFrom() as $email => $name) {
            $from_email = $email;
            $from_name = $name;
        }

        foreach ($message->getTo() as $email => $name) {
            $to_email = $email;
            $to_name = $name;
        }

        $options['form_params'] = [
            'from_email' => $from_email,
            'from_name'  => $from_name,
            'to_email'   => $to_email,
            'to_name'    => $to_name,
            'subject'    => $message->getSubject(),
            'body'       => $message->getBody()
        ];

        return $this->client->post($this->url, $options);
    }

    public function getKey()
    {
        return $this->key;
    }

    public function setKey($key)
    {
        return $this->key = $key;
    }

    public function getDomain()
    {
        return $this->domain;
    }

    public function setDomain($domain)
    {
        $this->url = 'https://api.mymailer.com/send?key=' . $this->key;

        return $this->domain = $domain;
    }
}
```

**Next step** is extending `TransportManager`. Because we have to add instructions for our custom Transport.

So it will be `SmithTransportManager.php` in model's directory or in `app` directory if you haven't separate directory for models.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Mail\TransportManager;

class SmithTransportManager extends TransportManager
{
    protected function createSmithDriver()
    {
        $config = $this->app['config']->get('services.smith', []);

        return new SmithTransport(
            $this->guggle($config),
            $config['secret'], $config['domain']
        );
    }

}
```

**Next step** is extending existing `MailServiceProvider`.

So our provider will be in `app/Providers/MailServiceProvider.php`

```
<?php namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider as MailProvider;

class MailServiceProvider extends MailProvider
{
    protected function registerSwiftTransport()
    {
        $this->app->singleton('swift.transport', function ($app) {
            return new \SmithTransportManager($app);
        });
    }

}
```

**And the final step** is modifying config files.

In the `config/app.php`

you have to remove (or comment line) standard `Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,`

And add `App\Providers\MailServiceProvider::class,` to the `providers` section.

In the `config/services.php` we have to add config getters:

```
'smith' => [
    'domain' => env('SMITH_DOMAIN'),
    'secret' => env('SMITH_SECRET'),
],
```

That's all! Hope it helps 'cause I didn't find any information in the docs of somewhere else about custom MailTransport.

Comment: guggle means Guzzle in 5.6>

Comment: @JamieRoss this answer was written based on real example designed with Laravel5.4. I'm not sure what have been changed since then

Comment: For laravel 5.6 or greater you just need to remove Swift_Mime_Message and replace it with \Swift_Mime_SimpleMessage

Comment: This worked perfectly on `Laravel 5.5`, however how do I identify an error in Api mail sent? Guzzle throw exception? Example:

    <?php
    function send(...) {
        ...
        $result = $this->client->post(...);
        return $result->getBody() == 'OK';
    }

    ...

Does `if (count(Mail::failures()) > 0) {` will work?

    <?php
        if (count(Mail::failures()) > 0) {
            $this->danger("Error sending e-mail to $to");
        } else {
            $this->info("Mail sent to $to");
        }

Comment: Well... it's depend on what you expect. Generally if you want to handle errors in API - you should implement error-reporting system with notifications but not in the user interface

Comment: Hi is there any way we can pass customer data to driver send method? Actually need to pass additional dynamic data to email driver.

Comment: @Objectobject Everything is possible. But the main question is "Why"?
Perhaps you just may only switcher that will select needed driver based on client's request

Comment: Actually I'm implementing Gmail API as driver so In driver send method I want to send additional data like mail belongs to which thread etc. Gmail API send method accept Gmail Resources as input so I've to build new instance from message with extra data and then send it.

Comment: @Objectobject ok, then your custom Transport need to accept extra parameters. But is there really no way to use smtp instead?

Comment: This sitepoint article has similar and useful information also: https://www.sitepoint.com/mail-logging-in-laravel-5-3-extending-the-mail-driver/

Comment: would this help me on taking advantage of laravel's email templates when sending mail through some mail provider api? for example sendgrid API: https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php#hello-email

Comment: @bermick partially. If you're using SendGrid templates instead of Blade, then you need to implement additional logic to prepare data for it

Comment: i want to use Blade templates instead of Sendgrid's

Comment: Then creating a provider will be enough